# date: extra operand '+%s'

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, amazon-s3

I'm running into a slight error that's not crashing my program per say but it brings it to a crawl. It keeps giving me the error:

```
date: extra operand '+%s'
```

It seems to really impact the speed of what it can process which is concerning seeing as I plan on deleting hundreds of thousands of log files. Here is the program in question:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./s3DeleteByDate "bucketname" "2m"
aws s3 ls s3://$1 | grep " DIR " -v | while read -r line;
do
 createDate=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1" "$2}')
 createDate=`date -d "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$createDate" +%s`
 olderThan=`date -d $2 +%s`
 if [[ $createDate -lt $olderThan ]]
  then
    fileName=`echo $line|awk {'print $4'}`
    if [[ $fileName != "" ]]
      then
        aws s3 rm  s3://$1"$fileName" --exclude "*" --include "*.tmp"
    fi
 fi
done;
```

Comment: Add `set -euo pipefail` to the beginning of the script, so you could have proper reaction to the errors. Then investigate what in `$createDate` parameter causes the problem.

Comment: @Velkan `set -e` is not always a good idea (see [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for example).  Better is just checking for expected results of each command

Comment: I answered this last night: `date +%s -d "$createDate"`. You are using GNU `date`, which doesn't allow you to specify an *input* format for the date.

Comment: I must've missed that. What would be the alternative? I think AWS is in CRON. I apologize, I'm still taking Linux classes but this is for work.

Comment: Is `"$createDate"` the date you want to have formatted? Then put a `-d` in front of it.

Comment: @Velkan, see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), skipping the allegory for the exercises below if in a hurry, to understand the objections to `set -e` -- or, perhaps even more clearly, the list of incompatibilities between different implementations at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed line 7 to: date +%s -d "$createDate".
This works because it's a GNU date, which doesn't allow you to specify an input format for the date. This fixes the error.

Comment: The answer by Tom already told you to do this -- all its examples have a `-d` before `"$createDate"`. Why did you add your own rather than accepting it?

Comment: His didn't work. The only thing that fixed it was moving the operand from the back of the command to the middle.

Comment: Which version of `date`? With GNU date, `date -d now +%s` (with the `%s` at the back) works perfectly. Same thing with the online interpreter at https://ideone.com/oem32p. Which is to say, I'm unable to reproduce that distinction.

Comment: 'date -d "$createDate" +%s'. It didn't stop giving me the error until I placed it infront of the '-d'.

Comment: Give me a command I can run, that stands on its own without any changes, to see the problem myself (ie. a complete command that *should* work but doesn't, because of the pattern being in the wrong position). For all I can tell, your `createDate` value was faulty when you were testing.

Comment: ...because to repeat myself again, `createDate=now; date -d "$createDate" +%s` works perfectly with `date` from GNU coreutils.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure of what you're asking of me. My linux skills are sub par as is.

Comment: I'm asking for a command I can run (without needing to set up any variables or whatnot ahead-of-time) to see the answer Tom gave fail for myself, in a situation where moving the `+%s` earlier makes that same command succeed. If you can get it to fail (and then succeed with a relocated `+%s`) in an online interpreter, such as http://ideone.com/, that would work too.

Comment: You're asking for things I just can't deliver, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You have two format specifiers in this line:

```
createDate=`date -d "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$createDate" +%s`
```

Presumably you meant to format `$createDate` using either:

```
createDate=`date -d "$createDate" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`
```

or:

```
createDate=`date -d "$createDate" +%s`
```

My money is on the second one, since you later use a numerical comparison in your `if`.

Comment: I tried both, for the first one it gave me: date: extra operand "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M". Then I tried the second way and it gave me the date: extra operand '%s'

Comment: Sounds like you didn't remove the extra format specifier from in the middle of the command.